# How to join 2 variables in a for loop(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying to combine 2 variables in a loop, as the code below show i need to add a number to every `var`, but i cant get it to work. This is just a part of a script. As you can see the `var item` should become `item1`, `item2`, `item3` and so on.

// the code

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    var item+' '+i = $('ul').find('.list-item-'+i).text();
}
```

Comment: you're missing a `var` on your `i`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use an arry:

```
var items = []
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    items[i] = $('ul').find('.list-item-'+i).text();
}
```

It's also important to see that

```
var item + ' ' + i
```

is an illegal declaration of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assign to elements of an array that is declared *outside* the `for` loop.

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Array:

```
var item=new Array();
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    item[i] = $('ul').find('.list-item-'+i).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Chango's answer above is perfect.**

However if you seriously need to store them as item1, item2, ... try this instead:

```
var tempArr=[];
var obj={};
for(i=0; i<10;i++) {
  tempArr.push('item'+i);
}
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
  obj[tempArr[i]]=$('ul').find('.list-item-'+i).text();
}
```

Now you can access item1 as obj.item1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do an explicit loop at all.

```
​var items = $("ul li[id^='list-item-']").map(function(i,o){
    return $(o).text();
}).get();​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/vM5Hy/

Comment: @amnotiam Was in the process of building that fiddle ;)

Comment: IMO, keep both solutions. The nice thing about your first one is that you don't need a trailing `.toArray()` or `.get()` *(not that they're an absolute requirement)*. Plus the `.text()` solution avoids the creating of multiple jQuery objects.

Comment: @amnotiam I've added in `.get` for good measure. I'm trying to keep the answer as simple and concise as possible.

Comment: Understood, though by "both" I meant your `.text(fn)` solution. I think the comments/edits were tripping over each other a little. Sorry for the clutter. :) Either way, this would be a good solution.

Answer (score -2):

I think that if you want to use vars like item1 or item2 your code should be :

```
var items = [];
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    items.push($('ul').find('.list-item-'+i).text());
}
```

But in your case i think that array should be better ...

Mimiz